# How can I set a variable to the activeElement?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I'm setting a string to an activeElement.value and everything works fine. Now I want to set a variable to the activeElement.value and I get the following error code:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   patientID is not defined Command duration or timeout: 66 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26
>   23:59:50' System info: host: 'MALTE', ip: '169.254.239.149', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_40' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false,
>   handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=37.0.1,
>   platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   9816aed6-75f7-48e2-90c5-4c018efd0af9  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:508)
>     at
>   defaultPackage.DataCapture.SelectExistingPatientByID(DataCapture.java:179)
>     at defaultPackage.DataCapture.main(DataCapture.java:50) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: patientID is not defined

The code with the variable (not working):

```
String patientID;
patientID = "n1n3";
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.activeElement.value = patientID;");
```

The part of the code with the string (working):

```
   jse.executeScript("document.activeElement.value = 'n1n3';");
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the value instead of variable. See the answer below.

```
    String patientID;
    patientID = "n1n3";
    JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("document.activeElement.value = '" + patientID + "';");
```

Comment: Yes, that makes much more sense! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad this is solution you wanted. Care accepting the answer?